# Configuring embedded Tomcat from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm searching about how to harden embedded tomcat according to CIS security Benchmark, how I can configure CATALINAHOME, BASE, and how can I configure the security manager with polices.

I did not find a flexible way to configure the embedded tomcat as stand-alone tomcat.

Any help regarding the customized of the embedded tomcat rather than the limited configuration in the `applicaiton.properties` .

Comment: you're asking how to configure the embedded tomcat

Comment: yes, how I can fully configure the embedded tomcat as the flexibility in configuring the stand-alone one.